# AS3 loop movieClip based on set timer

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, timer

I want to set a duration of time by hitting space bar twice. I then want a movieclip to play for that exact amount of time, then loop to play again at for that set amount of time, and so on. until I set a different amount of time by hitting the space bar twice again.

```
    var beat:int;
var beatcount:int;
var tempopress:int;
var num:Number;

num = 0;
tempopress = 0;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,checker);
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;



  var myTimer:Timer=new Timer(20,0);
  myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopWatch);



    function stopWatch(event:TimerEvent):void {
  beatcount = Number(myTimer.currentCount);

  }



    function checker(e:KeyboardEvent){  
     if(e.keyCode==Keyboard.SPACE){



  if (tempopress == 0) {
  trace('start');
  beatcount = 0;
  myTimer.reset();
  myTimer.start();
  tempopress = 1;

      } else {
          trace('stop');
          myTimer.stop();
          trace(beatcount);
          tempopress = 0;
          }


      }

 }


 stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopPlayback);

 function loopPlayback() {
     var loopTimer:Timer=new Timer(20,beatcount);
       myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loopWatch);
 }

     function loopWatch(event:TimerEvent):void {
        if (MovieClipMan.currentFrame >= MovieClipMan.totalFrames ){
        MovieClipMan.gotoAndStop(1);
    } else {
          MovieClipMan.nextFrame();
    }
    }
```

I know it's a mess haha. Please help! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd perhaps try something like this, which essentially is checking to see whether to do the loop or not each frame.

```
var timeStart:Number;
var loopDuration:Number;
var timeLastLoop:Number;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        if (!timeStart) { // First time SPACE is hit
            timeStart       = getTimer();

        } else { // Second time SPACE is hit
            loopDuration    = getTimer() - timeStart; // set the loop duration
            timeStart       = NaN; // reset the start time
            loop();
        }
    }
}

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if (loopDuration && timeLastLoop) {
        if (getTimer() >= timeLastLoop + loopDuration) { // if it's time to loop
            loop();
        }
    }
}

function loop():void {
    timeLastLoop    = getTimer();
    someMovieClip_mc.gotoAndPlay(0);
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother ya, but I'm now trying to make a separate movieclip loop at half the loop duration.. so it loops twice for every full loop. Is there a quick easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, use `getTimer()` to find the difference in time between space bar keypress.

Next, would be to stop creating a new `Timer` in every frame. It should be created outside of the enter frame handler. Then on the second keypress, you can set the `delay` property to the difference, and restart the timer.

The most important changes would be here:

```
if (tempopress == 0) {
    trace('start');
    myTimer.stop();
    startTime = getTimer();
    beatcount = 0;
    tempopress = 1;
} else {
    trace('stop');
    myTimer.delay = getTimer() - startTime;
    myTimer.reset();
    myTimer.start();
    tempopress = 0;
}
```

Then, the timer event handler can just send the MovieClip to frame 1.

Comment: thank you!

As it is I have 2 timers.. loopTimer and myTimer.. I probably only need one, right?